# I want to automatically fullscreen the command prompt in windows

Tags: cmd, vbscript, fullscreen, prompt

I tried to use this code:

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WinSendKeys "%(~)"
```

the code works in other programms but not in cmd prompt

Are there other options to put the prompt to fullscreen via command?

Answer (score 1):

Since Vista, the CMD window can't actually be made full screen (as was possible with <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>ENTER</kbd> in Windows XP); at best, you can set it to an arbitrary size in rows/columns to fit your screen size and font selection, via the shortcut properties. The buffer size properties in the shortcut must be at least as large as your proposed screen size in rows and columns, and if you set the size to larger than the screen can actually handle, you will end up with scroll bars. In any case, you can't actually suppress the title bar and border.

Answer (score 0):

Launch cmd and write the following:

```
mode 800
```